# is there anyway to open multiple instances of a dll?

Tags: delphi

I have one dll file ,but I want to have multiple instance of that dll at same time with different parameters , every time that i am doing LoadLibrary ,it return same handle and everything are same.
would you please suggest me a way to handle this .
FYI I dont want to copy dll files .
Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of a parameter to a dll?

Comment: I ask because you can't pass command line arguments to a dll.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I suspect the DLL exports a function/class that the app can use to store values in the DLL. So, loading multiple copies to try to store multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you would like to do is not possible. If you attempt to load a DLL that is already loaded, the systems returns the handle of the already loaded module, and increases its reference count.

Your question does point at the only available workaround. Make a copy of the file to a unique filename, and then load that.

Comment: `LoadLibrary()` is subject to [activation contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374153.aspx), though.  It searches for an existing DLL only in the currently active context.  What would happen if you load the DLL in one context, then switch to a different context and try to load it again?  I haven't tried it.  Does it only work for DLLs that are marked as isolation-aware?

Comment: I think only way is to copy file and load dll from new file .

Comment: is it possible to Load copy of DLL at memory then load different instance Library/Module from Memory ?

Comment: Probably that is possible although of course the OS does not support in memory dll loading without a backing file.